# Can someone compute a regular expression for apache access log files for Scala?

Tags: regex, scala

I am using the following regular expression in Scala

```
val Pattern = """^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+) (\S+) (\S+)" (\d{3}) (\d+)""".r

val res = Pattern.findFirstMatchIn(logFile)
```

Yet it is giving me the following error:

```
: Cannot parse log line: 80-219-148-207.dclient.hispeed.ch - - [07/Mar/2004:19:47:36 -0800] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide some example logs you're looking to parse?

Comment: Because the last `\d+` does not match. Try using an optional group around that last part: [`^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+) (\S+) (\S+)" (\d{3})(?: (\d+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/zB4sR5/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your regex expected the last parameter to be numeric (`\d+` - one or more digits), but it came as a `-` (unknown, undefined). The previous subpatterns worked OK because `\S+` (1 or more non-whitespaces) matches a hyphen.

So, either replace the last `\d+` with `\S+` or use alternation `(\d+|-)`. This latter approach can be extended to all the pattern parts like this:

```
^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] "(\S+) (\S+) (\S+)" (\d{3}|-) (\d+|-)
                                                                       ^^      ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE1pM2/1).